# The multi-part identifier could not be bound C# and SQL

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to execute a SQL query for a WCF service because the database I'm using doesn't have a stored procedure to return data I need.  You can see the code below. I'm using VS2010 and connecting to Microsoft SQL Server. The Exception I get is: The multi-part identifier could not be bound. Thanks for the help.

```
        public List<ObjectCodeGroup> GetObjectCodeGroup()
    {
        TCDataDataContext dc16 = new TCDataDataContext();
        List<ObjectCodeGroup> results = new List<ObjectCodeGroup>();

        var objectCodeResults = dc16.ExecuteQuery<ObjectCodeGroup>(@"select t1.codeid," +
            "t1.code, t1.catalogtype, t1.codegroup, t1.codetext, t1.codegrouptext, t1.codedesc, t1.state_id from CODES t1" +

            "inner join ( select MIN(codeid) codeid, codegroup from CODES group by codegroup)" +
                "t2 on t1.codeid = t2.codeid and t1.codegroup = t2.codegroup WHERE catalogtype = 11");

        foreach (ObjectCodeGroup o in objectCodeResults)
        {
            results.Add(new ObjectCodeGroup()
           {
               codegrouptext = o.codegrouptext
           });
        }

        return results;
    }
```

Comment: On what line?  You cannot provide us too much information, but it is very easy to not provide enough.  Can you run this query in SSMS?

Comment: Put some spaces at the end of the lines. Or just add line breaks in rather than `+` ing the individual lines as you are already using the `@` symbol.

Comment: @Jonesy, `from CODES t1 inner join (` look at `t1inner` being the alias of CODES

Comment: This can happen when you don't have access to some field in the query (the reasons could be account rights, schema, mistypes in names). On thing I notice is that in you query there will be a space missing between "t1" and "inner". And maybe between ")" and "t2". By the way, it's best to avoir writing queries in strings like this.

Comment: yeah im very off today, disregard me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you are missing a bunch of spaces, so that's part of the problem.  Add spaces (at the end of the lines)!

```
var objectCodeResults = dc16.ExecuteQuery<ObjectCodeGroup>(@"select t1.codeid, " +
"t1.code, t1.catalogtype, t1.codegroup, t1.codetext, t1.codegrouptext, t1.codedesc, t1.state_id from CODES t1 " +
"inner join ( select MIN(codeid) codeid, codegroup from CODES group by codegroup) " +
"t2 on t1.codeid = t2.codeid and t1.codegroup = t2.codegroup WHERE catalogtype = 11");
```

Your original query looked something like `SELECT BLAH FROM CODES t1inner join (MOREBLAH)...`.  Specifically, look at the `t1inner`.  That's what is gumming up the query.

Comment: Thanks Russell Uhl! That fixed it you saved me a huge headache.

Comment: @matt: glad I could help :)  In the future, if you absolutely must have a SQL string like that (rather than calling it up from a resource file or some other method), I advise breaking the string up at logical and consistent places.  For instance, `SELECT stuff` (br) `FROM table` (br) `JOIN other ON a = b` (br) `WHERE c = d` (br) etc.  It will make diagnosing such problems easier since the syntax will be in a better format

Comment: Russel, you saved my day! :)